# Where can I find Aramaic and Syriac Tools and References?

Tags: support, language

## 1. Question

When discussing Aramaic and Syriac Texts, what are resources that can be used to display Syriac fonts correctly, or even lookup passages in Aramaic / Syriac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Note:*** Posted as a community Wiki, please feel free to update.

**There are three different fonts available, at [CAL TTF font link](http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/fonts/pcfonts.html):**

- The Edessa font - which is great for Syriac;
- the Hebrew Translation font, which displays the Syriac characters as Hebrew;
- And a Hebrew Web font.

**Aramaiac, Syriac New Testament and Lexicons:**

- [biblehub.com](http://biblehub.com/pes/matthew/1.htm)
- [dukhrana.com](http://dukhrana.com/lexicon/search.php)

**Historical Aramaic and Syriac Manuscripts**

- [Comprehensive Aramaic Lexicon Project](http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/)

Comment: Edessa is in the Euphrates valley; Odessa is in the Ukraine.

Comment: @fdb - Thanks for the correction.  Updated!